# How do I target a specific Custom Java Component within a Mule Flow using MuleClient within a Unit Test

Tags: mule

I'm trying to wrap my head around how to write Unit tests for custom components and transformers.  How do you send a message to a specific Java Component?  I'm guessing I would use an instance of MuleClient within an @Test annotated method, but how do I address a specific component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Java component doesn't implement `Callable`, then unit test it like any Mule-unaware Java class you test. Nothing Mule specific in this case.

If it does implement `Callable`, the easiest is to create a test flow, add a request-response VM inbound-endpoint and the Java component in it. Then you can use the `MuleClient` to send test messages to the flow. Note that if your component modifies message properties, you will need a `copy-properties` element (or equivalent) in order to copy the modified properties to the outbound scope so you can assert them back in the unit test. Alternatively, you can add a `test:component` after your custom component but, because it only capture message payloads, you would need to register a custom `EventCallback` on it in order to capture the full `MuleMessage` for asserting properties.